# Setting .htaccess basic authentication and exclude subfolder /wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have an httpd server and WordPress site. I have been setting /.htaccess to authen when user access my domain. However, I want to access directly mydomain/wp-admin without authen. Here it's my file `.htaccess`, but not working:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^wp-admin\.php" noauth

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please login"
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=noauth

Satisfy any

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: This sounds like a very strange idea... You want to password protect the whole site _except_ specifically the most valuable and vulnerable section, the administration?

Comment: You still need username , without password yes you can but you need username , you can user `wp_set_auth_cookie()`

Comment: If your browser was loading _only_ `wp-admin.php` when you enter the admin area, this could make at least a bit of sense ... but since it requests lots of other resources as well (JavaScript, Stylesheets, Images), it of course doesn’t. Those will trigger the browser to ask you for credentials again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to login wihtout password yes you can, but you still need username since you have to set auth cookie in order authenticate.

Place following code to you function.php file

```
function admin_login($user, $username, $password) {
    $user = get_user_by("login", $username);

    if($user != "FALSE")
    {
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
    return $user;
}


function hide_password_field() 
{
    ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            body.login div#login form#loginform p:nth-child(2) {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    <?php
}

add_filter("authenticate", "admin_login", 10, 3);
add_action("login_head", "hide_password_field");
```

Now if you go to wp-admin, it will ask you only for username and let you login.

Comment: Thanks @shojibur. Can you tell me where is file I will place your code to execute?

Comment: Hi there, place inside function.php file

Answer (score 0):

I fixed but it seems not to work exactly my target. A normal user must input credential when access mydomain/, then admin user can directly access mydomain/wp-admin. However, after input correct user/password for WordPress, we received pop-up authentication from mydomain. How does it work? Drop me some solution.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-61 cms]$ sudo vi .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
# Do the regex check against the URI here, if match, set the "require_auth" var
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/wp-admin|^/wp-login require_auth=true

# Auth stuff
AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected!!!"
AuthType Basic

# Setup a deny/allow
Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from everyone
Deny from all
# except if either of these are satisfied
Satisfy any
# 1. a valid authenticated user
Require valid-user
# or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
Allow from env=require_auth


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-admin|^wp-login
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=x.x.x.x
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=x.x.x.x
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=x.x.x.x
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
```